# Minimum password length for registration form

Tags: users

For user registration, I have disabled "Require e-mail verification when a visitor creates an account." to allow user create their own password at the registration form. Now, I wonder how to limit the password characters to minimum 6? I have tested several times, it seems drupal doesn't restrict any password characters even user keys in just 3 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking of [Password policy](https://drupal.org/project/password_policy) module

> Features
>
> Current constraints include:
>
> - Complexity constraint
> - Digit constraint
> - Letter constraint Letter/Digit
> - constraint (Alphanumeric)
> - **Length constraint**
> - Uppercase constraint
> - Lowercase constraint Punctuation constraint
> - Delay constraint Username
> - constraint Digit placement constraint
> - History constraint (checks
> - hashed password against a collection of users previous hashed
> - passwords looking for recent duplicates)

Also checkout this [Quick demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nYD9c_tFtz8).